# beautiful soup doesn't find all the tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-scholar

I am trying to get the number of citations for a specific profile from Google Scholar. I use python and BeautifulSoup.

These elements are in the table *citations indices*. The code that I use returns only nine elements while there are more elements with the same tag when you click on the graph.

What's the problem?

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lista_url import*
url='https://scholar.google.gr/citations?user=aFYdVoYAAAAJ&hl=el'#profile-   scholar
webpage=urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage)
for t in soup.findAll('span',{"class":"gsc_g_al"}):
        a=t.text
        print a
```

Comment: What makes you think there are more elements? There really are just 9 such spans in the HTML returned. The other 4 hits for the class are for the CSS definition.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what results you were expecting here? You got the 9 numbers from the citations graph (one number for each year in the graph).

Comment: if you click on "citations indices" there are more years- more graphs which have the same tags ......so i can't understand what's the different between them?how can i print these?

Comment: Those extra citations are loaded via AJAX, they are not part of the page itself. You'll have to do the same, you won't find those with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: The URL looks rather easy to guess: `https://scholar.google.gr/citations?hl=en&user=aFYdVoYAAAAJ&view_op=citations_histogram`; note the extra `view_op=citations_histogram` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The larger citations table you appear to be looking for is loaded asynchronously using JavaScript (an AJAX request). You'll have to do this in your own code.

The URL for the AJAX request simply adds a `view_op=citations_histogram` parameter:

```
url='https://scholar.google.gr/citations?user=aFYdVoYAAAAJ&hl=el&view_op=citations_histogram'
```

This produces 24 entries:

```
>>> url='https://scholar.google.gr/citations?user=aFYdVoYAAAAJ&hl=el&view_op=citations_histogram'
>>> webpage=urlopen(url)
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage)
>>> len(soup.find_all('span', class_='gsc_g_al'))
24
>>> [el.string for el in soup.find_all('span', class_='gsc_g_al')]
[u'2', u'5', u'1', u'4', u'9', u'6', u'2', u'2', u'2', u'7', u'23', u'15', u'21', u'12', u'26', u'20', u'38', u'32', u'6', u'38', u'38', u'39', u'87', u'10']
>>> [el.string for el in soup.find_all('span', class_='gsc_g_t')]
[u'1992', u'1993', u'1994', u'1995', u'1996', u'1997', u'1998', u'1999', u'2000', u'2001', u'2002', u'2003', u'2004', u'2005', u'2006', u'2007', u'2008', u'2009', u'2010', u'2011', u'2012', u'2013', u'2014', u'2015']
```